# Can I change the size of the kde menu?

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, kde-4, desktop-customization

I would like to make the menu bigger (=covering more of the screen and showing more), is that possible?

Using opensuse 13 kde

Comment: Can you not just drag the corner of the menu to the size you want it to be?